# How can a C# class be written to test against 0 as well as null

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, class-design

**BACKGROUND:** I have a custom class written in C# (2005), with code similar to the following:

```
public class Savepoint
{
  public int iOffset;                 /* Starting offset in main journal */
  public u32 nOrig;                   /* Original number of pages in file */
  public u32 iSubRec;                 /* Index of first record in sub-journal */
};
```

After a variable has been declared with **Savepoint sp;** I can test to see if has been instantiated with code similar to:

```
if (sp != null) {...}
```

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to overload the class operator somehow so that I can also use the following syntax as well: **if (sp)  {...}** or **if (sp != 0)  {...}**

PS: I have no real good reason for wanting to write if (sp) other than force of habit.

Comment: Perhaps explaining the good reason will help get a more palatable answer.

Comment: That's why I added the PS, there is no "good reason", just my ingrained programming habits, and curiosity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can add an implicit cast to bool... something like this should work.

```
public static implicit operator bool(Savepoint sp)
{
    return sp != null;
}
```

Example:

```
Savepoint sp1 = new Savepoint();
sp1.iOffset = 4;
Savepoint sp2 = new Savepoint();
Savepoint sp3 = null;

Console.WriteLine("sp1: " + (sp1 ? "true" : "false")); // prints true
Console.WriteLine("sp2: " + (sp2 ? "true" : "false")); // prints true
Console.WriteLine("sp3: " + (sp3 ? "true" : "false")); // prints false
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I'll accept your answer if you change your code to eliminate the iOffset test in the operator bool, something like

return (sp != null)

Comment: You can choose either implicit or explicit. If you use explicit rather than implicit you have to explicitly cast it too bool to work... if ((bool)savePointVar) { ...}

Answer (score 17):

You might be able to do that in C# using the default property decorator, but you shouldn't. Trying to write C# like it was a duck-typed language will lead to all sorts of cognitive dissonance down the line.

As a rule of thumb, it's a good idea to embrace the vernacular of the language you're working in rather than trying to cram it into a more-familiar shape it was never meant to hold.

Answer (score 3):

The if statement in C# takes a boolean expression and doesn't do type conversion to boolean if the expression is non-boolean, unlike in C (or Javascript).  My advice is to just deal with the minor annoyance and use the standard C# idiom.